# How to make PHP str_replace less lengthy

Tags: php, string, replace

I have following codes.

```
$obj->symbol = str_replace('PR.', 'p', $obj->symbol);
$obj->symbol = str_replace('UN.', 'u', $obj->symbol);
$obj->symbol = str_replace('RT.', 'r', $obj->symbol);
$obj->symbol = str_replace('WT.', 'w', $obj->symbol);
$obj->symbol = str_replace('PR', 'p', $obj->symbol);
$obj->symbol = str_replace('UN', 'u', $obj->symbol);
$obj->symbol = str_replace('RT', 'r', $obj->symbol);
$obj->symbol = str_replace('WT', 'w', $obj->symbol);
```

As you can see, this looks really ugly. How can I reduce this into fewer lines?

Comment: `$obj->symbol = strtr($obj->symbol, array('PR.' => 'p', ...));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most I would recommend would be condensing lines that have the same replacement:

```
$obj->symbol = str_replace( array( 'PR.', 'PR'), 'p', $obj->symbol);
```

At least this is still maintainable and readable. If you condense this into one line with two massive arrays, you should store the array as a `key => value` replacement map, and use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr) instead:

```
$replacements = array(
    'PR'  => 'p',
    'PR.' => 'p' 
    // etc
);

$obj->symbol = strtr( $obj->symbol, $replacements);
```

Comment: I found this answer to be more visually pleasing. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can pass an array into the function. Do something like this:

```
$obj->symbol = str_replace(array('PR.','UN.'), array('p','u'), $obj->symbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm a little late to the party, but i've always been a fan of preg_replace_callback():

```
$good_string = preg_replace_callback('/([PURW])[RNT]\.?/',function ($matches){
  return strtolower($matches[1]);
},$bad_string);
```